# How can I start the numbering of Figure (and sections) in the appendix from 1?

Tags: numbering, appendices

I am trying to make an appendix section. I use

```
\begin{appendix}
...
\end{appendix}
```

However, the figures and sections start with the numbering of my last Chapter - 6. How can I make them start from 1?

Comment: Please show us a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that helps us to reproduce your problem and to find a solution. Currently we even do not know the class you are using or whether or not you are using a package that provides an `appendix` environment instead of an `\appendix` command. So my only suggestion would be: Use `\setcounter` to set the values of the counters you want to start from 1. But maybe this wouldn't be the best solution.